# Knapsack problem with a constraint

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

I am familiar with 0/1 knapsack problem.
But if the following constraint is imposed... how do I solve the question?

1. If you choose some item 'U' you won't be able to choose another item 'V'.

For example
Items are given as [Name, Weight, Value]
Items are : 
A 10 20
B 50 80
C 20 30
D 30 70
E 50 50

If you choose B then you cannot choose A.
If you choose E then you cannot choose C.
If you choose D then you cannot choose A.
In the similar way the constraints are given.

Please provide me some way to solve the above problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you model it as an [integer linear program](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)?

Comment: `If you choose B then you cannot choose A.` - is that relationship symmetric?  That is, if choose A first, then does that mean I still choose B second?  Or does it also imply A and B can't be in the same knapsack regardless of selection order?

Comment: Yes the relation is symmetric. If A is chosen B cannot be chosen and vice versa. A and B cannot be in the same knapsack.

Comment: Please edit the mutuality of exclusion into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard dynamic programming approaches are likely not going to work for this problem, because the extra "this or that but not both" constraints destroy the [overlapping subproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems) property. So let's break out the sledgehammer.

You can easily encode this as a [0-1 integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem and use an off-the-shelf solver. For the given example (and some maximum weight limit $W$), a suitable 0-1 ILP problem is:

maximize $20A + 80B + 30C + 70D + 50E$
subject to
$A, B, C, D, E \in \{0, 1\}$
$10A + 50B + 20C + 30D + 50E \le W$
$A + B \le 1$
$C + E \le 1$
$A + D \le 1$

Although, it is not obvious to me that an integer linear programming solver will take full advantage of the structure of the problem. So perhaps a more specialized solution may perform better in practice.

Comment: Thank you so much